# javascript window.location not working

Tags: javascript, url

I am new to javascript, and stuck on this problem. I am trying to have the url query string change based on which checkbox checked. But I seem to have some issue with window.location, Some of the JavaScript is below

```
  var urltest= window.location.pathname;
  var urltest2 = window.location.host;
  var currentURL  = urltest2 + urltest;
  url = currentURL + "?" + arr_opts.join('&');

  document.getElementById('myurl').innerHTML = url;

  //window.location.href = url;
  window.location = url;
```

The window.location does not work here, but when I change var currentURL to

```
var currentURLL = window.location.href;
```

it is work, but not with

```
  var urltest= window.location.pathname;
  var urltest2 = window.location.host;
  var currentURL  = urltest2 + urltest;
```

I need window.location to point page to the currentURL above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you found that using `.href` works, why not just use that?

Comment: using .href would add the query string to a url with aquery string in it already. So i would have something like http://localhost/kdd/aasd.php?category=1?category=1?category=1?category=1

Comment: If you want the same URL but a different query string, just set the location to the new query string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not providing a protocol, so the `location.href` change is being treated as "go to this relative path from the current location", i.e. on this page

```
window.location = window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
// takes us to
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254564/javascript-window-location-not-working/stackoverflow.com/questions/35254564/javascript-window-location-not-working/35254601
```

Do one of the following

- Provide a protocol so it knows it is an absolute URI,

  ```
  window.location = window.location.prototcol + '//' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?foo=bar';
  ```
- Tell it to re-use the current protocol but work as an absolute URI

  ```
  window.location = '//' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?foo=bar';
  ```
- Provide an *origin* (instead of *host*)

  ```
  window.location = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + '?foo=bar';
  ```
- Tell it to re-use the same origin but work as an absolute path

  ```
  window.location = window.location.pathname + '?foo=bar';
  ```
- Just update the query

  ```
  window.location = '?foo=bar';
  ```

Always choose the most simple option to make your life easier if you ever need to debug, i.e. if you can assume you will always want the same protocol, host and path, just update the query.

---

Useful knowledge

Starting a URL with..

- `//` means *same protocol*
- `/` means *same origin*
- `?` means *same path*
- `#` means *same query* (will not re-load)

Answer (score 0):

The `pathname` is going to be something like `/questions/35254564/javascript-window-location-not-working`, and the `host` is something like `stackoverflow.com`. If you put those together with code like yours, you get

```
stackoverflow.com/questions/35254564/javascript-window-location-not-working
```

That's clearly not correct; the host looks like part of the pathname. You can use `protocol` and `port` if you really feel the need to reconstruct the URL from its constituent parts, but using the `href` seems simpler if all you want to do is add a query string.